# Fortify scan FPR file download through Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, fortify

My team and I have a need to automatically (script) the download of Fortify Scan FPR files in SCC and store these in another location and we are looking for options on how to do this. At the moment, I am researching if it is possible for Jenkins to actually perform this task though a Jenkins job. I understand that Jenkins is capable of uploading FPR files through the 'HP_Fortify_Jenkins_Plugin_TN' and viewing the results of the FPR files but I don't see anywhere if it is possible to do the download of .FPR files and copy these to another location.

Is Jenkins capable of downloading the FPR files (through a Jenkins job)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fortify has a Maven Plugin that you can invoke from Jenkins. You can also use the ant integration with Fortify. Looks up Fortify Maven integration, there are a number of resources online. If you have a copy of Fortify, it should have a copy of the Fortify Maven plugin.